# Accessing Service Fabric with reverse proxy and SSL from custom domain

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

By following many docs/tutorials I implemented SSL with Kernel and reverse proxy in my SF. 
I made it work but the access point Url is as follow : https://mycluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19081
before I implemented https, I had a CNAME mycustomdomain.com redirecting to mycluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com which was working fine.
So now, I would like to know if there's a way to call http://mycustomdomain.com 
and access the actual Uri. Is there a way with what I already have in place through probes/lbrules for example? Or do I have to implement an Application Gateway or use API management or something else?

Edit : LBRules+Probes

```
AppPortProbe : 44338 (backend ssl port in the SF)
FabricGatewayProbe : 19000
FabricHttpGatewayProbe : 19080
SFReverseProxyProbe : 19081

[Rule : Probe]
[AppPortLBRule (TCP/80 to TCP/19081) : 19081]
[LBHttpRule (TCP/19080) : 19080]
[LBRule (TCP/19000) : 19000]
[LBSFReverseProxyRule (TCP/19081 to TCP/44338) : 44338]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to godaddy or whichever domain provider you use and add a transfert to your your azure domain : https://mycluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

Answer (score 0):

You question is too broad, there are too many questions that might bring many answers, I will try to answer with a few options:

In your scenario, to access the same url you should use `https://mycustomdomain.com:19081` instead.

The problem here is, when you setup the cluster, the certificate used by the cluster is valid only for the domain 'mycluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com' in your case your domain is not valid in the certificate used by SF and it will fail once you make any request to it.

You can skip certificate validation errors on your browser and continue. In your applications you could do the same, the problem is that is not a friendly way doing it.

To be able to use the domain without any conflicts, you have to register your own certificate created for the domain you own.

Because you are using reverse proxy, you also have to define the certificate in the cluster configuration, look for: `reverseProxyCertificate` in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#enable-reverse-proxy-via-azure-resource-manager-templates)

For deploying applications using SSL will happen something similar, but in your application you can define the certificate you want to use on startup, in the cluster you have to define it in the cluster configuration.

You can find more information here:
[Manage service fabric cluster security certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure)

If the problem is the port, you have two options:

1. Create a 'Port forwarding' rule in the load balancer, to forward any
   request in the port 80 to port 19081. You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-ps#create-the-configuration-rules-probe-and-load-balancer) how to do that with powershell.
2. Update the cluster/service configuration to listen in the port
   80 instead of 19081. [check it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#enable-reverse-proxy-via-azure-resource-manager-templates)

Comment: I can't really ask a client to access my website and tell him he should specify https and the port of my reverse proxy at the end. it has to be just mydomain.com which will bring him the content of https://mycluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19081, question is, where and how can I do this mapping

Comment: I have added extra info to the answer. If the problem is the port you have to add a load balancer forwarding rule, if is the certificate, you have to register it in the cluster and the reverse proxy, You described that you don't want your customer to type anything beyond the domain, do not forget that the reverse proxy by itself won't bring you any website\service to the client if they just type your domain in their browser, they still have to pass the ApplicationName and the ServiceName, if you are exposing a website, you are using the wrong service for it.

Comment: I only use unsigned certificates on a dev server so far, so no problem with that. At the moment, using https://mycluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19081 brings me to the backend port of my asp.Net core 2 angular project so it's exactly what I need, if i can just replace that url by my domain url. So if it is achievable through load balancing, how should I configure it? I never had to do any networking before ... atm I have this (updated post), what should it be?

Comment: I have added the link to customize custom port forwarding rules. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-ps#create-the-configuration-rules-probe-and-load-balancer

Comment: tried solution 2, got some fabric_e_invalid_address and timeouts, will give a shot to option 1

Comment: link in solution 2 seems to be the same as I did in the azure portal except in powershell, it doesn't explain how to forward 2 external ports (80 + 443 to 19081, can’t add same backend port in 2 rules and I would need to foward those 2 external ports to the external 19081 not internal, wouldn't I ?). It doesn't really explains as well what probes or rules I would need too setup as well

Comment: fabric_e_invalid_address might be because other services are using this port in you cluster.

Comment: On load balancer rules you would have to register two rules, one for each inbound port and both rules will have the same outbound port, that is the port of your service. If your service is running on https, the inbound rule will be 443 and outbound 19081 for example. You might also get certificate errors and nothing will be displayed, can be this the problem. I am not sure if you can use the port 80.

Comment: if I try to redirect on the same outbound, azure gives out this error message : The protocol and port combination you entered matches another rule used by this load balancer. The protocol and port combination of each load balancing rule and inbound NAT rule on a load balancer must be unique.

Comment: am I suppose to modify NAT rules as well to do it? how?

Comment: I just tried this out : [AppPortLBRule (TCP/44338) : 44338]
[LBSFReverseProxyRule (TCP/443) : 443], giving out an error 400

Comment: [LBSFReverseProxyRule (TCP/443) : 443]
 => error 400

Comment: [LBSFReverseProxyRule (TCP/443 to TCP/44338) : 443]
 => https://my_cluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com redirects to https://my_cluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/home ; https://customdomain.com gives ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: ok made it work keeping these settings, it was a godaddy issue